# My click event does not work with new li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a code, which will create a new li elements and append it to the ul, and then by click i need to add a 'selected' class to the element and by clicking again remove this class, it works fine with li elements which already exists, but it does not work with new elements which i'm adding, and i can't understand why...

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var button = document.querySelector('.container a'),
  list = document.getElementById('list'),
  li = list.children;

 $(button).on('click', function() {
  var li = document.createElement('LI');
  var word = prompt('Enter a word');
  var text = document.createTextNode(word);
  li.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(li);
  console.log(list.children);
 }); // click event

 $(li).on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
   $(this).removeClass('selected');
  } else {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
  }
 }); // click event

 // console.log(li);
});
```

actually code is pretty simple, i'm little bit confused why it does not work.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Mixing direct DOM calls with jQuery code is probably not the best coding style. Either use jQuery, or use the native DOM.

Answer (score 5):

You're using jQuery, so this is pretty easy:

```
 $("#list").on("click", "> li", function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("selected");
 });
```

The code above creates a *delegated* event handler. The handler is attached to the list container, so it will catch all events that bubble up from within. That means that you can add `<li>` elements freely, and the events from new ones will be handled exactly like events from old ones.

Answer (score 3):

It's not working, because you are creating new DOM elements and these elements have no listeners attached to them. Replace your code with this.

```
   $("body").on('click', "li", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    }); // click event
```

## Edit:

In case you need this. I have created a vanilla event handler, which will attach event handlers to all elements.

`fakejQuery == jQuery's $` but a simpler version of it :). The code works in IE8+, where in IE8 you can use only CSS2 selectors

```
window.fakejQuery = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)
eventHandler: function (element, eventType, fn) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        for (var i = fakejQuery(element).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            fakejQuery(element)[i].addEventListener(eventType, fn, false)
        }
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
        for (var i = fakejQuery(element).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            fakejQuery(element)[i].attachEvent("on" + eventType, fn)
        }
    } else {
        alert("Ooops, no event listener methods found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `li` contains the current children so it will make no difference, you should use a selector there.

Comment: Thanks everybody, i understand the problem and solution)